# Is expression evaluated before assigning type?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I am assigning type to an $\lambda$-expression: `if false then M else N`
where `if A then B else C` and `false` have their usual meanings (read: not specified).

The problem arises because M and N have different types. While clearly the expression evaluates to N & hence *should* be assigned type(N) but apparently it is expected that for `if-else`, the types for B & C should be same.

How to proceed on this? Should I use conjuncted type?

Comment: What do you mean by conjuncted type?

Comment: I may have used the word "conjunction" incorrectly. I'm referring to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/818351/593987)

Comment: That sounds like intersection types. Do you also have union types?

Comment: No, I don't think we have covered them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type checking is something that happens before evaluation.

In most common type systems for lambda calculus, including simply typed lambda calculus and System F, `if false then M else N` is ill typed if `N` and `M` have different types. Unless you have been told otherwise you are probably working with one of these.

There are extensions such as union types and certain forms of subtyping that allow `if false then M else N` to be well formed with `N` and `M`having different types.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you suggest some books/authoritative references to study this further from?

Comment: I haven't read either myself, but two I have seen recommended by others are " Practical Foundations for Programming Languages" by Robert Harper and " Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin Pierce.